# Is there a better way of attaching javascript to multiple HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Apologies for the muddled title - can't find the best way of phrasing this.

I have a textarea and word count as follows:

```
<textarea class="form-control caption-box" name="caption" id="caption" rows="5"></textarea>

<span class="pull-right label label-default count-message" id="count_message"></span>
```

And then I show a word count using javascript.

```
   $('#caption').keyup(function() {
      var text_length = $('#caption').val().length;
      var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
      $('#count_message').html(text_length+' characters');
    });

    var text_length = $('#caption').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    $('#count_message').html(text_length+' characters');
```

I need to add 6 more textareas on the page, all with the word count functionality. I could just recreate the javascript 6 times and change the element identifier but that feels inefficient.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Does each textarea have a different `count_message` or something similar?

Comment: You can easily target them using the class caption-box instead by the different ids and target the different count_message elements (in case there are more than just the one) relative to the textarea.

Comment: @CertainPerformance they will have different count_messages. But can change if that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes to select the textareas, and from the handler, dynamically navigate to the associated `caption` element. Eg, if they're next to each other, you can use `.next()`:

```js
const maxLength = 100;
function showRemaining() {
  const currLength = $(this).val().length;
  const remaining = maxLength - currLength;
  $(this).next().text(remaining + ' characters');
}

$('.caption').on('input', showRemaining);
$('.caption').trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
```

This is quite trivial to accomplish without jQuery, unless it's essential for something else, feel free to remove it as a dependency:

```js
const maxLength = 100;
function showRemaining() {
  const currLength = this.value.length;
  const remaining = maxLength - currLength;
  this.nextElementSibling.textContent = remaining + ' characters';
}
for (const caption of document.querySelectorAll('.caption')) {
  caption.addEventListener('input', showRemaining);
  caption.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
}
```

```html
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
<textarea class="caption" rows="5"></textarea>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is great thanks. I'll post the final code that worked for as a separate answer but the $(this).next() is what helped me crack it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that worked:

HTML x 6

```
<textarea class="form-control caption-box" name="caption" id="caption" rows="5"></textarea>

<span class="pull-right label label-default count-message" id="count_message"></span>
```

Javascript

```
$('.caption-box').each(function() {
  var text_length = $(this).val().length;
  $(this).next().html(text_length + ' characters');
});

$('.caption-box').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $(this).val().length;
  $(this).next().html(text_length + ' characters');
});
```